# Cannot use this in a static context android spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to add few items in the spinner list. But somehow everytime, I always get the below exception on `this`-

```
Cannot use this in a static context
```

Below is my code

```
  public static void initSpinnerView(Context context, Spinner spinnerView, String prefix, int numItems, int layout) {

    //spinnerView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this
```

This is a Java keyword indicateing the current object. If I am not wrong, this method is placed in an class that extends Activity. Hence, `this` refers to the Activity object( which is used as Context in this case). And since it is a static method, you cannot used the keyword `this` or non-static variables.

In order to fix it,change to this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Answer (score 2):

In java you can not use this in static methods (static context).

Static methods do not point to any instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: Thanks zibi. How can I overcome the above problem then?

Comment: There are several different possibilities - remove the static modifier, change this to the proper instance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this in static method which is not legal in java.